# Assignment to property of function parameter 'a' Eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am trying to sort array of object with custom function. 
So, I define my function

```
   sortingAlgo = (a, b) => {
        // we need to use custom sorting algorithm to meet our requirements.
        a.pos = a.pos.toUpperCase();
        b.pos = b.pos.toUpperCase();
        if(a.pos.slice(0, 1) === b.pos.slice(0, 1)) {
          if (parseInt(a.pos.slice(1)) < parseInt(b.pos.slice(1))){
            return -1;
          }
          if (parseInt(a.pos.slice(1)) > parseInt(b.pos.slice(1))){
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        } else {
          if (parseInt(a.pos.slice(0, 1)) < parseInt(b.pos.slice(0, 1))){
            return -1;
          }
          if (parseInt(a.pos.slice(0, 1)) > parseInt(b.pos.slice(0, 1))){
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;

        }
      }
```

And i call it like this.

```
const sortedProducts = data.data.sort(this.sortingAlgo);
```

Now i Got Eslint error saying.

**

- 169:5   error    Assignment to property of function parameter 'a' 
  no-param-reassign
- 170:5   error    Assignment to property of function parameter 'b' 
  no-param-reassign

**

I searched and found that this rule is set byt airBnB. So i dont think its right to disable this rule.

So can somebody tell me how to resolve it or if disabling this rule is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to reassign the `pos` property of the function arguments (`a, b`). You should just assign a new variable (`aPos, bPos`), which is a best practice, hence why ESLint is complaining.

You should avoid unnecessary [mutations/side-effects](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) whenever possible in your code to prevent bugs and create an overall more efficient program architecture.

More specifically in this case..

[ESLint: Disallow Reassignment of Function Parameters (no-param-reassign)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign)

```
const sortingAlgo = (a, b) => {
    // we need to use custom sorting algorithm to meet our requirements.
    let aPos = a.pos.toUpperCase(),
        bPos = b.pos.toUpperCase();

    if (aPos.slice(0, 1) === bPos.slice(0, 1)) {
        if (parseInt(aPos.slice(1)) < parseInt(bPos.slice(1))) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (parseInt(aPos.slice(1)) > parseInt(bPos.slice(1))) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (parseInt(aPos.slice(0, 1)) < parseInt(bPos.slice(0, 1))) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (parseInt(aPos.slice(0, 1)) > parseInt(bPos.slice(0, 1))) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You ESLint is configured to not allow re-assignment of parameters, i.e if a function takes 2 arguments (a, b), then you CANT re-assign these 2 variables in the function body.

To fix this error, either:

- disable the eslint rule (in your .eslintrc or just for the function)
- create new variables to avoid re-assigning to a and b (see below):

```
 sortingAlgo = (a, b) => {
        // we need to use custom sorting algorithm to meet our requirements.
        const aPos = a.pos.toUpperCase();
        const bPos = b.pos.toUpperCase();
        ...
```

Then replace references to `a.pos` and `b.pos` to `aPos` and `bPos`.